# Concatenate cells

Tags: matlab, concatenation, cell-array

I have a 6 x 12 cell (called **M**) like this

```
[1 1 1 1] [2 2 2 2] ... [12 12 12 12]
[13 13 13 13] [14 14 14 14] ... [24 24 24 24]
...
[61 61 61 61] [62 62 62 62] ... [72 72 72 72]
```

I would like to vertically concatenate so the matrix would become 1 x 12 cell which should look like this:

```
[1 1 1 1 13 13 13 13 ... 61 61 61 61] [ 2 2 2 2 14 14 14 14 14 ... 62 62 62 62] ...
...
```

I've tried `vertcat`, for instance `vertcat(M{1,1}, M{2,1})` but that doesn't seem to work. Could anyone please help?

Comment: some for loops would do the trick. Also, cells are accessed with curly brackets, not parenthesis

Comment: Hi Ander, can you please elaborate on the loops? I don't quite get "some for loops". And you're right about the curly brackets. Sorry, it's been corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all the cells' contents have the *same size*, as in your example, you can concatenate everything into a matrix and then convert to a cell array:

```
result = mat2cell(cell2mat(M.'), ones(1,size(M,2))).';
```

As an example, for

```
M = { [1 1 1 1] [2 2 2 2]
      [13 13 13 13] [14 14 14 14]
      [61 61 61 61] [62 62 62 62] };
```

this produces

```
result{1} =
     1     1     1     1    13    13    13    13    61    61    61    61
result{2} =
     2     2     2     2    14    14    14    14    62    62    62    62
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm in an `arrayfun` ra(m)page so, my *50 Cent*s of MATLAB:

```
result = arrayfun(@(x) [M{:,x}], 1:12, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do the job:

```
% test data
M{1,1}=[1 1];M{1,2}=[2 2];
M{2,1}=[3 3];M{2,2}=[4 4];
M{3,1}=[5 5];M{3,2}=[6 6];


newcell=cell(1,size(M,2));

for ii=1:size(M,2)
    newarray=[];   
    newarray=[newarray, M{:,ii}]; %catch next array and contatenate
    newcell{ii}=newarray;
end
```

Comment: I believe the `for jj` loop can be (efficiently IMHO) replaced by `newcell{ii} = horzcat(M{:,ii})`. And avoids growing arrays in memory.

Comment: @A.Rainer thanks! However, if your matrices are the same size, probably CST-link and Luis answers are better. ;)